# Run loop on the server with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, socket.io

Let's say i need to constantly collecting some data from a lot of clients and in parallel running some complex loop that solving some stuff with this data. How can i do it? Should i just write this in my piece of code:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/views/index0.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    // SOME STUFF WITH THE SOCKET
    socket.on('disconnect', function(data) {
       //SOME OTHER STUFF
    });

});

while(...) {
    //THE LOOP STUFF
}
```

Or i need to use the setTimeout() and setInterval() functions? How can i do the loop on the server that runs in parallel with the callbacks' stuff?

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve?  You can use `while()` anywhere you want in your server, but you don't say what you're really trying to accomplish on the server.  node.js only runs one single Javascript thread.  If you really want to run "background" processing, then you need to fire up another node.js child process and do processing there.  But, if you're only doing I/O kinds of things, not heavy CPU processing, then you can just do your normal work and it will interleave just fine with regular request processing.  A more detailed answer needs to see your actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don’t use while for make it, this block a thread. setTimeout() will run only once. You need to use setInterval() function.

Comment: And make sure it's inside `io.sockets.on('connection')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/) module to handle the async operation with the callback or use [promise](https://developer.ibm.com/node/2016/08/24/promises-in-node-js-an-alternative-to-callbacks/) to avoid callback.

Here how I handle a complex async for each operation, that might helpfull to you get idea handeling ayncs forach

```
var cond = { _schedule: schedule_id }; // find curse by schedule id
Course.find(cond, function (err, courses) {
    if (err) {
        callback({ "success": false, "message": "Not able to update" });
    } else {

        async.forEachLimit(courses, 1, function (course, coursesCallback) {
            async.waterfall([
                function (callback) {
                    var schedule_date = moment(change_data.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "T00:00:00.000Z"
                    var Assignmentcond = {
                        assignment_schedule_order: {
                            $gte: schedule_date
                        },
                        _course: course._id,
                        _schedule: schedule_id,
                        _user: userid
                    };

                    Assignment.find(Assignmentcond)
                        .populate({
                            path: '_course',

                        })
                        .lean()
                        .sort({ assignment_schedule_order: 1 })
                        .exec(function (err, AssignmentList) {
                            if (err) {
                                callback(null, '');
                            } else {
                                //console.log("------------------AssignmentList---------------------------");
                                //console.log(AssignmentList);

                                async.forEachLimit(AssignmentList, 1, function (ThisAssignmentCell, ThisAssignmentCellCallback) {

                                    async.waterfall([
                                        function (callback) {
                                            var SearchObj = items;
                                            var lebelObject = {};

                                            for (var i = 0, flag = 0, insert = 0; i < SearchObj.length; i++) {

                                                if (SearchObj[i].date == ThisAssignmentCell.assignment_schedule_date) {
                                                    flag = 1;
                                                }
                                                if (flag == 1 && SearchObj[i].label != "") {
                                                    if (ThisAssignmentCell.day == SearchObj[i].day_index) {
                                                        insert = 1;
                                                        var lebelObject = SearchObj[i];
                                                        break;

                                                    }

                                                }

                                            }




                                            callback(null, ThisAssignmentCell, lebelObject, insert);
                                        },
                                        function (ThisAssignmentCell, SearchObj, insert, callback) {
                                            console.log('----------------------');
                                            console.log('ThisAssignmentCell', ThisAssignmentCell);
                                            console.log('SearchObj', SearchObj);
                                            console.log('----------------------');

                                            if (insert > 0) {

                                                var query = { _id: ThisAssignmentCell._id },
                                                    fields = {
                                                        assignment_date: moment(SearchObj.date).format('MM/DD/YYYY'),
                                                        assignment_schedule_date: moment(SearchObj.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                                                        assignment_schedule_order: new Date(SearchObj.date),
                                                        day: SearchObj.day_index,
                                                        dayNum: SearchObj.weekday_num
                                                    },
                                                    options = { upsert: false };

                                                Assignment.update(query, fields, options, function (err, affected) {
                                                    callback(null, '');
                                                });


                                            } else {
                                                //                                                                                                    var cond = { _id: ThisAssignmentCell._id};
                                                //                                                                                                    Assignment.remove(cond)
                                                //                                                                                                          .exec(function (err, cnt) {
                                                //                                                                                                             callback(null, '');
                                                //                                                                                                    }); 

                                            }



                                        }
                                    ], function (err, result) {
                                        // result now equals 'done'
                                        console.log('done')
                                        ThisAssignmentCellCallback();
                                    });


                                }, function (err) {
                                    console.log("Assignment For Loop Completed");
                                    callback(null, AssignmentList);
                                });



                            }
                        });



                }
            ], function (err, result) {
                // result now equals 'done'
                console.log('done')
                coursesCallback();
            });
        }, function (err) {
            console.log("courses For Loop Completed");
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: Wow, this is a **lot** of code to explain a small concept. Can you at least trim it down to the most important bits?